# Organize multiple NSURLSessionTasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have an iOS app that can download files from a website. I have created a `NSURLSession` in a class `Downloads` to manage them. The `Downloads` class has a `NSMutableArray` that keeps track of all current and past downloads using my `DownloadItem` objects. I am not happy with this setup.

Currently, I have to have the `Downloads` class as the delegate for all downloads. I see no way to assign the delegate of each `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to a `DownloadItem` object. So, I have to keep it assigned to my `Downloads` object and then have it figure out which way `DownloadItem` to forward the message on to.

Currently I do this by making an NSMutableDictionary called `tasksDictionary` in the `Downloads` and use the `taskIdentifier` as a key.

```
return [self.tasksDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:task.taskIdentifier]];
```

This seems to work, but it doesn't seem the most efficient method. I'm also concerned that I saw the first taskIdentifier created was `0` which will make it difficult to discern the difference between a completed task and the first task.

Is there a better way to keep track of these things? Is there a way to assign a new delegate for a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps have these ivars:

```
NSMutableArray *completedDownloads;
NSMutableDictionary *activeDownloadTasks; // @(taskID) => DownloadItem
```

When you finish, pop the `DownloadItem` from `activeDownloadTasks` and add it to `completedDownloads`.

Otherwise what you are doing sounds peachy.

While I'm at it, this syntax may be helpful (using your example):

`return self.tasksDictionary[@(task.taskIdentifier)];`

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing, but it is nice to have a confirmation that I'm doing the right thing.